# filling the content of union produce error

Tags: c, typedef, unions

I try to fill the content of a union with something, however I receive an error. here's the code:

```
struct command
{
    int type;
    int *input;
    int *output;
    union{
        struct command *command[2];
        char **word;
    }u;
};

typedef struct command *command_t;

command_t read_command(){
    command_t main1 = NULL;
    command_t main2 = NULL;
    main1->u->word = (char**)malloc(1);
    main1->u->word[0] = (char*)malloc(1);
    //some other code in here
}
```

I got an error in "main1->u->word = (char**)malloc(1);" line saying: "invalid type argument of â->â (have âunion â)"

any suggestion? thx

Comment: Use `main1->u.word`, you'll also have to use `malloc` to get `main1`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `main1->u.word = ...`. (dot instead of arrow after `u`.)

But your code contains multiple other errors which the compiler will not find:

You cannot assign to anything in main1 and main2 since these pointers are `NULL` pointers. Allocate some memory for them first.

The first malloc just allocates a single byte, but your `char*` needs 4 or 8 bytes. To make this work use:

```
main1->u.word = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

assuming you want to allocate an array of `char*` of length 1.

The second malloc also allocates just a single byte. How much data do you want to store here?

Comment: by allocating some memory first, do u mean something like "command_t main1 = (command_t)malloc(sizeof(command_t));"?

Answer (score 0):

`main1->u` is an union, and not a pointer-to-union, therefore you can't use the `->` operator on it.

Furthermore, you don't allocate enough space for the pointer (`malloc(1)` returns a pointer to a memory block which is 1 byte large, and I doubt that that's what `sizeof(char **)` is). You are also casting the return value of `malloc()`, [which is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). What you want is

```
main1->u.word = malloc(sizeof(*main->u.word));
main1->u.word[0] = malloc(LENGTH_OF_STRING + 1); // for the NUL terminator
```

instead.